# In C++ why does reference to single character of std::string give a number

Tags: c++, string, character, substring

I have a string like this:

```
std::string N;
```

I assign a (test) value like this:

```
N = "Ant";
```

To print the first character, I did this:

```
std::cout << N[0];
```

But the output is `65` (i.e., the ASCII value) and not the actual letter.
So I tried this:

```
putchar(N[0]);
```

**Why does it give a number and is there an alternative to putchar** where I can avoid using the old header file `stdio.h`?

Thanks!

Additional info: 
Compilter: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Complete code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 std::string N;

 N = "Ant"; 
 std::cout << N[0]; //output 65
 putchar(N[0]); //output A
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
g++ c.cpp -o c
```

Comment: You can cast, of course, but it's still a nice question why std::cout prints the number. It doesn't for me, though.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/3w04Mq#view_edit_box)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Compiler used GCC/G++ On Ubuntu and the same is on Windows.

Comment: Show us a complete example code.

Comment: Works on gcc 4.7.1, see [demo](http://ideone.com/dAUR8J).

Comment: A *complete* example program is needed to answer this question, because there is some important detail to the problem that isn't in your question, as you can see from the links in the comments above.

Comment: That works [as expected](http://ideone.com/htq1qJ).

Comment: Your code sample compiled with gcc 4.6.3 in Ubuntu will *not* print `65`.  Can you please verify that you compiled that *exact* code and also verify that the file date of the resulting binary is *newer* than the file date of the source code?

Comment: If this problem is real, then either someone messed with your compiler, and it treats chars as ints, or someone messed with your standard library.

Comment: Always pass `-Wall` to `g++`. And use just `g++ -v` to check what version of GCC you are really using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Debian/Sid/x86-64 the below program (in source file `itsols.cc` compiled with the command `g++ -Wall itsols.cc -o itsols`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int, char**) {
  std::string s = "Hello";
  std::cout << s[3] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

displays a single lower-case `l` (compiled with `g++ -Wall itsols.cc -o itsols`, both with GCC 4.7.2 and with GCC 4.8.0 and also with GCC 4.6.3)

So I cannot reproduce what you claim (and I believe you are probably wrong, because when you read C++ reference material the [operator [] on strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) gives a `const char&` result, which is output using `std::cout <<` as a single char, not a number).

### addenda

Even by taking your [final] example (which is not correct C++ because `main` has a bad signature, and GCC warns about that) I am getting two `A` outputs (and this using either GCC 4.6.3, or GC 4.7.2, or GCC 4.8.0). Also, your example lacks a `std::endl` and a final `putchar('\n'); return 0;` ....

Take the habit to always pass `-Wall` to `g++` or `gcc` (also passing `-g` while you debug your program with `gdb`, later optimizing it with  `-O2` when there is no bugs), and also check with `g++ -v` that you are running the compiler you believe, and to get its version.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Apparently it was an issue with the compiler. I don't know what. But owing to your nice explanation on the `main` signature I accept your answer. I'm pretty new to GCC/G++ as I'm making a come-ack from the old Turbo C ver.1 and I see so many differences :) Thanks!

Comment: Take the following good habits: use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/documentation), even for small single-person projects. Use a good editor (like `emacs`). Compile with `g++ -Wall -g`. Improve the code till not warnings are given. Learn to use the `gdb` debugger and [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to build multi-source file programs. Take advantage that Linux is **free software** so you can study (and improve) the source code of any software you want.

Comment: @itsols Does it still go wrong with your compiler? You could try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Comment: @MrLister I'm not sure WHY but a few things have happened since the problem occured. apt-update, build-essentials, restart... I'm not sure what fixed it. But I think I'll stick to Basile's approach until I get this sorted out. I'm no GCC expert. I'm bringing in my old code (20 years old) from Turbo/Borland C and I see that this is a whole different thing starting from the headers :)